# Proper way to add a non-restful custom method to Active Resource class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeresource

I have route that looks like this:

```
/orders/preview
```

It returns something like:

```
<order><total>100</total></order>
```

I want to add this method to an active resource class. What is the best way to do this?

I started doing something like this:

```
class Order < ActiveResource::Base
  def self.preview(params = {})
    post(:preview, params)
  end
end
```

This appears to work, but I get a `Net::HTTP` response back rather than an `Order` object.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what you're trying to accomplish here. What is preview supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about `POST`, but if you just wanted to do a `GET`. Have you tried this?

http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.1/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html#method-c-find

```
Order.find(:all, :from => :preview)
# => GET /orders/preview.json
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with different formats being processed... I have solved this by explicitly stating what formats I want to use like this:

in ActiveResource model, set self.format parameter

```
class Order < ActiveResource::Base
    self.site = "http://lbv.me"
    self.format = :json  
end
```

In ActiveRecord model, if you use 'respond_with' method you actually must state what format you expect it to respond with, like this:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
respond_to :html, :json

def show
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
   respond_with @user
end
.
.
.
end
```